Is there any way to avoid multiple definition error?
I'm trying to build a program and seeing multiple definition issue.
Here is the simplified source codes and a makefile.
I understand this mutiple definition error.
But somehow I saw this was compiled in my work environment.
I cannot bring my work environment here.
Is there any way to avoid multiple definition error using a special gcc options?
Or is some version of GCC able to handle this issue?
[Source code 1 : main.c]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "data.h"

int main(void)
{
   test_cfg.a1 = 1;
   printf("test_cfg.a1 = %d\n", test_cfg.a1);

   func();
   return 0;
}

[Source code 2 : func.c]
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "data.h"

int func(void)
{
   test_cfg.b1 = 12;
   printf("test_cfg.b1 = %d\n", test_cfg.b1);

   return 0;
}

[Header file : data.h]
#ifndef _DATA_H_
#define _DATA_H_

struct {
  int a1;
  int b1;
  int c1;
} test_cfg;

int func(void);
#endif /* end of _DATA_H_ */

[Makefile]
CC = gcc
AR = ar
ARFLAGS = rcs

CFLAGS += -Wall -std=c99

SOURCE=./main.c ./func.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)

all: app_test

app_test:$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o app_test

[Output]
$ make
gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 main.c
gcc -c -Wall -std=c99 func.c
gcc -o app_test ./main.o ./func.o
/usr/bin/ld: ./func.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `test_cfg'; ./main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:13: app_test] Error 1



Do not define variables in .h files. These should be used for declarations only (unless there is some very specific cases). Define test_cfg in one of the c files, and declare it as extern in the .h file so it is accessible from other .c

@EugeneSh.: There is nothing in the data.h header shown in the question that is a definition as specified by the C standard. There are complications regarding tentative definitions (which are not definitions), so “Do not define variables in .h files” is an inadequate statement.

@EricPostpischil I think it refers to a linker message like "multiple definition of ", so that one can be blamed for complications in terms of definitions

@yvs2014: The issue with the comment is not whether we end up with multiple definitions, the issue is communicating the problem to a reader confronting this issue. There is more information in the question I marked this as a duplicate of.
